# uploading a new protege ontology file on Jena Fuseki

Tags: webserver, jena, fuseki, protege4

How do I upload onto a remote machine a new ontology (.owl file) using the Fuseki web-server installed on my Mac?

I can authenticate and log in, but the first thing I would have to do is to select a data graph that is already there. Before picking the graph, I do not see any options to upload or update anything.

How can I upload a new Protege file through Fuseki?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can load the file by running this line on the shell:

```
./fuseki-server --file=path-to-my-file/my-file.owl /myowl
```

after you can access the ontology in:

```
http://localhost:3030/myowl
```

Comment: I think this will load the OWL file as data. You'll be able to treat it as a bunch of triples and query it but if you want reasoning, inference or any other ontology related stuff, I don't think this is what you want.